# Permutation of first few integers in Python

Tags: python, permutation

I want to go through all permutations of (1,2,3,4,5) in Python and calculate something for each permutation, like

```
for li in PermutationLists: # PermutationLists = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,5,4],...]
    print li[0]-li[1]+li[2]-li[3]+li[4]
```

What would be a convenient way to iterate through all these permutations of (1,2,3,4,5)?

Comment: `itertools.permutation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ashwini Chaudhary pointed out in the comments:

```
from itertools import permutations

permutes = permutations([1,2,3,4,5])

for li in permutes:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Why do you store the permutations object in a variable? Why not simply iterating it?

Comment: for no reason in particular